# Double click on titlebar to maximize / restore windows?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, window, titlebar, doubleclick

How can I configure a double click on titlebar to maximize / restore windows? Making shortcuts for keyboard is easy, but so far I haven't been able to find any answer on how to do the same with mouse clicks (!)

Should be pretty simple and neat, but also highly widespread across the different platforms.

All I could find myself, was some instructions for `Emerald Theme Manager`, a project dead in '11, and cannot be found through apps.

Thanks in advance, and merry Christmas to y'all! :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use *(GNOME) Tweaks* to achieve your goal.

Launch Tweaks and go to the *Windows* section. Select "*Toggle Maximize*" for "Double-Click" under **Titlebar Actions**.

[image]

Or simply open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-double-click-titlebar 'toggle-maximize'
```